# What is the question "If G is group of order 360 what are the possible isomorphism types of the Sylow p-subgroups for p=2,3,5,7?" really asking?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, group-isomorphism, sylow-theory

What is the question "If G is group of order 360 what are the possible isomorphism types of the Sylow p-subgroups for p=2,3,5,7?" really asking?

I am familiar with the Sylow theorems, but not with the term "isomorphism type".

Comment: The possible isomorphism types of groups of order $4$ are $C_4$ and $C_2\times C_2$, for example. The answer is expected in this sense. By the way, there is also a simple group of order $360$, namely $A_6\cong PSL_2(\Bbb F_9)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isomorphic groups form an equivalence class under the equivalence of isomorphism. These classes are known sometimes as "isomorphism types". The question is asking for what groups the groups are isomorphic to.